# JSON object not retrieved on server

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am passing JSON object by stringifying it in ajax. But it is not retrieved on server side.

```
jsonData = {
    "10001":{
        "2":["33","","8","","9",""],
        "name":"abc",
        "token":"10001",
        "01":["","36","","1","1","8"]
    },
    "10002":{
        "2":["67","87","78","5","44",""],
        "name":"dfds",
        "token":"10002",
        "01":["9","","7","3","5","7"]
    }
}
```

The Object is passed using ajax as under :

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(emp);                   
$.ajax({
    url: "SaveController",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",                  
    data: {empData:jsonData},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: false,
    cache: false,                        
    success: function(response){
        alert("Data Saved...");
        alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    error: function(err){
        alert("Error in Saving Data...");
        alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

and I am retrieving it in my SaveController as under

```
response.setContentType("application/json");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
try {
    String term = request.getParameter("empData");                      
    System.out.println( term);       
} finally {
    out.close();
}
```

Have checked on neturl on client side data is sent as parameter string in post but not being retrieved with getParameter on the server side. It is returning null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through many articles the tweak that made it work is 
by removing
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",